# How to create a moving average based on time values in a separate column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have physiological data collected over a specific period of time in excel. I have the time points in one column and the measures in a separate column. I want a macro that will automatically average the first 10 minutes of physio data, move to the start of the next 10 minutes then average that and so on and so forth for the entire data set.

I've been trying to combine the averageIfs and offset functions in a way that does this but I keep hitting a wall. Help please?

```
=AverageIfs((Offset(A2+10/1440)), D:D,A:A,">="& A2,A:A,"<"&(A2+10/1440))
```

I was hoping this would average and then at least move to the next cell after the averaged range. Instead I got an error message that says not enough arguments. I realize there are a lot of problems here, and that I can't accomplish my goal with a single line of code but this feels a bit out of my depth and I could use help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You should post some data example, with the input you have, and the expected output.